# cv2.VideoCapture.read() isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I took an image via opencv to check if I have some problem with webcam but webcam is working. Now in below mentioned code only else statement is being executed and frame is none all the time.

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if video.isOpened():
    while True:
        check, frame = video.read()  
        if frame != None:
            cv2.imshow("Color Frame", frame) 
            key = cv2.waitKey(50)        
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
        else:
            print("Frame not available")
            print(video.isOpened())
```

Comment: what is `check` equal to after the read?

Comment: `check` is `False`

Comment: If you use linux check if there is `/dev/video0`

Comment: I am using 64-bit windows 7

Comment: Have you tried cv2.VideoCapture(1) or cv2.VideoCapture(2) ? It's possible that your code cannot access your primary camera driver

Comment: My primary camera is working and I took a photo with it. Now I can't figure out what's wrong when I start a video capture

Comment: Did you see the `Video Source` popup windows for you to `Select a Video Device`? If so, did you see your camera name showed in that `Video Device` pull down menu? Your code is a basic one and it works well in my PC.

Comment: In my case when I pass -1 like `cv2.VideoCapture(-1)` then it shows the popup and I can select my webcam in that popup. passing 0 means it will use the webcam and if we pass 1 it means it will use the first external cam.

Answer (score 0):

In Raspberry Pi 3, I had to do the following to get it to work:

```
$ sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

Answer (score 0):

cv2.Videocapture.read() returned false,None, the solution was to run :
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda install -c conda-forge opencv